# Create new column based on two columns

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two text columns in a dataframe and I would like to create a third column that puts TRUE if the the two columns are identical and FALSE if they are not.  Right now the code below will put a new colunmn in the dataframe but it is all NAs.  I need to figure out how to do an if then statement so that it returns something other than NAs.  Basically it is like in Excel where you can use the = sign and point to two columns and then TRUE or FALSE is returned.  Can anyone help me?

```
combinedData$SourceAgree<-combinedData[combinedData$Source==combinedData$SouceID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate approaches:

```
combinedData <- data.frame(Source=1:4,
                           SourceID=c(5,6,3,4))
combinedData$SourceAgree <- ifelse(
  combinedData$Source==combinedData$SourceID, TRUE, FALSE)
within(combinedData, {
  Agree <- Source==SourceID})
```

giving:

```
  Source SourceID SourceAgree Agree
1      1        5       FALSE FALSE
2      2        6       FALSE FALSE
3      3        3        TRUE  TRUE
4      4        4        TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer @dardisco. I don't understand why you would want to produce two identical columns

Comment: Hi, This code does work.  The only issue is when there is an NA in both columns FALSE will be returned.  But to get around that I could code the NAs as some fake category and then it would work perfectly.  THANKS SO MUCH!